# Change click value alternately javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to exchange value from X to O alternatively after one and second click on the div element. I success to create the X after one click. How can I change the second click to O value and trade them off ?

```
 <div id= "content" style="width: 300px;height: 300px; background:gray;">

 </div>
```

javascript

```
const boardArea = document.getElementById("content");
boardArea.addEventListener("click", createDot)

function createDot(event){
// create a span with X after one click and append it to div
const dot = document.createElement("span");
boardArea.appendChild(dot);
dot.innerText="X";

dot.style.color  =  "red";
dot.style.position  =  "absolute";
dot.style.top  =  event.pageY + 'px'; 
dot.style.left  =  event.pageX + 'px'; 

}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, would you like to toggle between "X" and "O" ?

Comment: yes something like that

Comment: You can create a variable that contains the current state of X or O and simply use an if statement for that

Comment: yes this solution in your link extends me more posibilities to do it. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const boardArea = document.getElementById("content");
boardArea.addEventListener("click", createDot)
var currentValue = 'X';
function createDot(event){
  // create a span with X after one click and append it to div
  const dot = document.createElement("span");
  boardArea.appendChild(dot);
  dot.innerText = currentValue;
  currentValue = currentValue === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';

  dot.style.color  =  "red";
  dot.style.position  =  "absolute";
  dot.style.top  =  event.pageY + 'px'; 
  dot.style.left  =  event.pageX + 'px'; 

}
```

```html
<div id= "content" style="width: 300px;height: 300px; background:gray;">

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there's multiple ways of doing this and I'm sure this can be shorter but something like this might work:

```
...    
let currentVal = 'O';
if(currentVal === 'O'){
    currentVal = 'X';
    dot.innerText = currentVal;
} else {
    currentVal = 'O';
    dot.innerText = currentVal;
}
```

This is shorter and might work but I'm not sure about the implementation details of `.innerText` so that's why I didn't suggested this as a first solution:

```
if(dot.innerText === 'O'){
    dot.innerText = 'X';
} else {
    dot.innerText = 'O';
}
```

Comment: I tried this it kept giving me only one value

Comment: That's probably cause the variable is scoped within the function... Try either the second solution or pass the current value as a parameter to the function so you can preserve the value. Or take out the variable out of your function to preserve state...

Comment: it sould be inside the function because the span element is created inside the function so that the values are kept reproducing after click